# What is the expiry policy of Google OAuth2 access tokens for Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm working on authenticating REST API calls to a Firebase Realtime database and have decided to use Google OAuth2 access tokens to authorize the requests. I've followed this doc -
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth

and used this code to generate new access tokens

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Define the required scopes
scopes = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database"
]

# Authenticate a credential with the service account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    "path/to/serviceAccountKey.json", scopes=scopes)

# Or, use the token directly, as described in the "Authenticate with an
# access token" section below. (not recommended)
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)
access_token = credentials.token

print(access_token)
```

My questions are -

1. What is the expiry policy of these access tokens?
2. how many of them can I generate?
3. How can I fetch all the active tokens and remove one or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the expiry policy of these access tokens?

Standard google access tokens last an hour.

> how many of them can I generate?

I dont think there is a limit

> How can I fetch all the active tokens and remove one or more?

You cant really access tokens are not stored they contained access.  Look up bearer token.

## None of those questions matter

You are using a service account.  Service account is a different type of access its client access.  Its not going to expire as long as you dont delete the service account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please tell me more about the not-expiring service account. I essentially want to create a token which does not expire within an hour.